# Is a mycelium sewage pipe possible?

Tags: mycology, mushroom

Over the past few years I've seen mycelium used as a supplement for various building materials. I was wondering if mycelium could be successfully used as construction material for a sewage pipe.

Furthermore, would this sewage pipe be able to provide any filtering of waste, given the mycelium?

Sources:

- [mycelium packaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecovative_Design)
- [mycelium plastics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnMXH5TqqG8)
- [mycelium bricks](http://www.psfk.com/2014/06/mycotecture-fungus-bricks.html)

Comment: Providing some reference to instances in which mycelium have been used for building materials previously would strengthen this question. Further, perhaps a quick comment about why you want to know this information -- this would help guide those providing answers to stay relevant for you.

Comment: @theforestecologist agreed — please offer examples of mycelium incorporation into construction!

Comment: I'm assuming [here](http://www.cnn.com/2016/09/16/world/ecovative-mushroom-furniture/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRnJeNurdEY) are examples of what the OP is referring to? I'd seen both of these stories about 7 or 8 months ago I think.